# Angularjs timing issue retrieving values and displaying .

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi in my controller I have following code that fetches data from db. It is fetching data correctly there is no problem as I can see it in firebug.

```
 $scope.up = supRepository.getPrice.query({ id: sup._id }, function(data) {
                $scope.up = data;
            });
            alert($scope.up.description);
```

Problem is that on alert it just gives me empty box nothing in it. No error or value. 
I believe this might be related to timing?
Please let me know how can i fix it. So if it is timing issue it waits until the values are available.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the alert into the callback so you know you have already received `data`

```
supRepository.getPrice.query({ id: sup._id }, function(data) {
      $scope.up = data;
      alert($scope.up.description);
});
```